# c# Function Converting 2D Array to Image Problem

Tags: c#, image, function, matrix, arguments

I Made this Function:

```
  public Image intArrayToImage(int[] inputarray)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(inputarray);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

And in the main function:

```
Color[,] finalarray= new Color[1600, 1600];
finalarray = intingArrayToImage(grayscale_map));
```

where grayscale_map is a 2d array  "grayscale_map[1600x1600]"

But There is an error like this:

**CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[ *, * ]' to 'int[ ]'**

What should i do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `intArrayToImage` has as an argument an array of integers (one dimensional) and you pass a two dimensional array of integers.

You could re-declare your method, `intArrayToImage` as below:

```
public Image TwoDimensionalArrayToImage(int[,] twoDimensionalArray)
{
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, twoDimensionalArray);
        return Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the namespace for "BinaryFormatter" it gives error

Comment: @SadViolinMan `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;`

Comment: ok that worked. one more question. i saw that actually i needed to be return as a color. not image :). i realised it now. can you show me also how can i return it as color. changing image to color didnt work :) it worth to try though. and also which type of variable i can assign it if it return as an image.

Comment: @SadViolinMan I don't know how you could this :(